# Make whiptail work in a for loop

Tags: bash, scripting, for, whiptail

I have a bash script that checks ping for 163 sites(stores around the country), which is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#storestest.sh
#version 0.9.2

clear;
printf "Check stores procedure started; `date +"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"`\n";

declare -a STORESITE=($(cat 'stores.txt' | awk -F, '{print $1}')); # Declaring an array and populated by the file stores.txt
declare -i UP=0; # Create a variable to serve as a counter for stores that are up
declare -i DOWN=0; # Create a variable to serve as a counter for stores that are down

touch storesdown.txt; # Create a file if does not exist to store the list of the store the stores that are down
printf "" > storesdown.txt; # Clear the contents of the file
touch storesup.txt; # Create a file if does not exist to store the list of the store the stores that are up
printf "" > storesup.txt; # Clear the contents of the file

whiptail --title "Testing stores connectivity" --backtitle "Store Test" --yes-button "OK" --no-button "Cancel" --yesno "Check stores procidure has started" 10 50

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    exit;
fi


for i in "${STORESITE[@]}" ; do
    ping -c 3 $i > /dev/null 2> /dev/null;
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$i is up" >> storesup.txt;
        let UP++
        sleep 1
    else
        echo "$i is down"  >> storesdown.txt;
        let DOWN++
        sleep 1
    fi
    printf "Total: $UP are online and $DOWN are off line.\r";
done

echo "Total: $UP are online and $DOWN are off line.";
exit;
```

The above script is working fine but I decided to make it a bit fancier by adding a gauge to show the total progress of it.
So here is what I did next:

```
#!/bin/bash
#storestest.sh
#version 0.9.3

clear;
printf "Check stores procedure started; `date +"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"`\n";

declare -a STORESITE=($(cat 'stores.txt' | awk -F, '{print $1}')); # Declaring an array and populated by the file stores.txt
declare -i UP=0; # Create a variable to serve as a counter for stores that are up
declare -i DOWN=0; # Create a variable to serve as a counter for stores that are down

touch storesdown.txt; # Create a file if does not exist to store the list of the store the stores that are down
printf "" > storesdown.txt; # Clear the contents of the file
touch storesup.txt; # Create a file if does not exist to store the list of the store the stores that are up
printf "" > storesup.txt; # Clear the contents of the file

whiptail --title "Testing stores connectivity" --backtitle "Store Test" --yes-button "OK" --no-button "Cancel" --yesno "Check stores procidure has started" 10 50

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    exit;
fi

total="${#STORESITE[*]}";

{
for ((g = 0; g <= $(( $total -1)); g++)); do

    for i in "${STORESITE[@]}"; do
        ping -c 3 $i > /dev/null 2> /dev/null;
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "$i is up" >> storesup.txt;
            let UP++
            sleep 2
        else
            echo "$i is down"  >> storesdown.txt;
            let DOWN++
            sleep 2
        fi
        printf "Total: $UP are online and $DOWN are off line.\r";
    done
    sleep 1
    echo $g
  done
} | whiptail --gauge "Please wait" 6 60 0


echo "Total: $UP are online and $DOWN are off line.";
exit;
```

Which does not work as I thought it should be.... That was the best way I could think and write to make at least the whiptail work, but apparently what it happens is to skip the nested loop.

P.S I know some of my coding is obsolete and old fashion way of bash scripting.

Comment: This line has a typo: "for i in "${WEBISTE[@]}"; do"

Comment: Yep just found it and correct it. Before I jump to check the stores I did some testings with websites, so that's why that variable has that name. Change and correct it but the problem still exists. Thanks fro the comment Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Your script has an extra loop (which is executed anyway).  It is pinging the array *subscript* rather than the subscripted member of the array.

Here is a version without the extra loop (and pinging the expected `$site`):

```
#!/bin/bash
#storestest.sh
#version 0.9.3

clear;
printf "Check stores procedure started; `date +"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"`\n";

declare -a STORESITE=($(cat 'stores.txt' | awk -F, '{print $1}')); # Declaring an array and populated by the file stores.txt
declare -i UP=0; # Create a variable to serve as a counter for stores that are up
declare -i DOWN=0; # Create a variable to serve as a counter for stores that are down

touch storesdown.txt; # Create a file if does not exist to store the list of the store the stores that are down
printf "" > storesdown.txt; # Clear the contents of the file
touch storesup.txt; # Create a file if does not exist to store the list of the store the stores that are up
printf "" > storesup.txt; # Clear the contents of the file

total="${#STORESITE[*]}";

whiptail --title "Testing stores connectivity" --backtitle "Store Test" --yes-button "OK" --no-button "Cancel" --yesno "Check stores procedure has started, with $total stores" 10 50

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    exit;
fi

{
UP=0
DOWN=0
for ((g = 0; g <= $(( $total -1)); g++)); do

    site="${STORESITE[$g]}"
    ping -c 3 $site > /dev/null 2> /dev/null;
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$site is up" >> storesup.txt;
        let UP++
    else
        echo "$site is down"  >> storesdown.txt;
        let DOWN++
    fi
    # sleep 2
    # stdbuf --output=L printf "Total: $UP are online and $DOWN are off line.\r"
    stdbuf --output=L echo $(( ( g * 100 ) / total ))
    sleep 1
  done
} | whiptail --gauge "Please wait" 6 60 0

online=$(wc -l storesup.txt | awk '{print $1;}')
offline=$(wc -l storesdown.txt | awk '{print $1;}')

echo "Total: $online are online and $offline are off line.";
exit;
```

Other fixes:

- I used `stdbuf` to make the output *line-buffered* (which helps make the gauge work as expected).
- The redirection makes `UP` and `DOWN` in a subprocess, so the totals did not get to the last line.  I worked around that by counting the number of lines in the output files.
- Finally, it shows a percentage in the progress bar.